# Can't instantiate parceable Object

Tags: java, android, serialization

I created a parceable class and wanted to use it for data transfer from fragment A to B. I did it like in many other tutorials but I can't instantiate from parceable object class. it always says, that I have to put in 'Parcel in' as parameter.

Here my object class:

```
public class DataObject implements Parcelable {

private int number1 = 0;
private int number2 = 0;
private String name = "";

public int getNumber1() {
    return number1;
}

public void setNumber1(int number1) {
    this.number1 = number1;
}

public int getNumber2() {
    return number2;
}

public void setNumber2(int number2) {
    this.number2 = number2;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

protected DataObject(Parcel in) {
    number1 = in.readInt();
    number2 = in.readInt();
    name = in.readString();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(number1);
    dest.writeInt(number2);
    dest.writeString(name);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Parcelable.Creator<DataObject> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<DataObject>() {
    @Override
    public DataObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new DataObject(in);
    }

    @Override
    public DataObject[] newArray(int size) {
        return new DataObject[size];
    }
};
}
```

And here is how I use objects from this type:

```
DataObject bla = new DataObject();
bla.setNumber1(1);
bla.setNumber2(2);
bla.setName("TestName");
```

When I hover the red highlighted constructor it says:

> DataObject (Parcel) in DataObject cannot be applied

and compiler says:

> Error:(30, 50) error: constructor PointCardMainData in class 
>   PointCardMainData cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: Parcel
>   found: no arguments
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Has anybody an idea what is missing? Do I have to set something in the manifest- oder gradle-file? do I have to do something before building the project?

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written just one constructor in the `DataObject` class, and it specifies how to make a `DataObject` from a `Parcel`.  Now you're trying to make a `DataObject` without a parcel.  You need to *either* add a `Parcel` to the line `DataObject bla = new DataObject();` *or* add a new constructor.

So you might write

```
 Parcel theParcel = new Parcel();
 DataObject bla = new DataObject(theParcel);
```

Or you might have a constructor in your `DataObject` class like

```
public DataObject(){
}
```

Comment: THX. On the first hand I'm sure I tried your (and user3374345s) solution... I really wonder why it's working today. Sometimes I have the feeling you have to restart android studio to get the right behaviour...
On the other hand I wonder why in most of the parcealable Object tutorials there is no hint, that you have an empty constructor...

Answer (score 1):

Add a constructor in your DataObject class

```
public DataObject()
{}
```

Comment: THX! this was to easy :-P